# How fine-grained can Actors be?

Tags: scala, akka

This is a beginner Akka question (And maybe I am seeing Actors everywhere)

I have an sql table "books". (5 million rows) The queries I want to run need to be as fast as possible. The where clauses are quite complex. And I want the queries to run under a sec. That is why I need a pure memory solution

Does it make sense to have an actor for each book row?

With this design I would have a "bookManagerActor" which would manage its 5 million child "bookActors"

The "bookMangerActor" should reply to messages like "filter books of date" or "sort books by date and name" (the sorting and filtering could take some time and the filters can be composed)

Or should I just use a java.util.Set in my bookManagerActor?
Do I get any benefits from modelling single books as Actors?

Comment: What benefits are you hoping to get by creating 5 million actors? It sounds like you're trying to leverage Akka to sort your lists, but you should really let the database handle that--it's what it was designed for. Not sure what you mean by using a `Set`, but if that also means keeping 5 million things in memory, that will probably not go well.

Comment: actually the books are categorized in projects. So when a request comes in the bookManagerActor loads the right books into memory. the bookManagerActor may also cache the filters applied to the books.

Comment: @m-z the sort on the database is too slow. that is why I am trying to brink akka in the game. I want to do things like pre-filtering...

Comment: Then either your indexing is poor, or you need a new choice of database. If you're trying to implement sharding, maybe take a look at ElasticSearch, which handles things like that for you. Sorting 5 million records in memory probably won't be better than the database's capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any benefit of using actors in this case, and yes 5 Million actors are some what demanding.

I would use immutable HashMap to store books within a cache actor.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

Comment: that's what I am also feeling... But 5 million would just mean 1.9 GB if an actor is 400 kb)

Comment: @jack **Plus** whatever you store within that actor, which will add up very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limited number of concurrent connections to the database you can handle, so it makes no sense to create more actors than that - they will have to wait for each other to make queries. I would suggest to have one actor for the whole table which can eventually delegate the queries to "workers", ie. its child actors. The actor-manager will count how many connections there are left and either create a worker for a new query or send the query to an already existing worker.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned it in the question. the sql queries and sorting just take too long. I need an pure memory solution. I'll edit the question

Comment: In that case I would suggest rather to optimize the queries or change the db engine than copying all 5 million books into the memory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to recreate standard DB functionality (sort and filter).  Those are quite complex topics and a lot of people spent a lot of time solving those.  A normal DB will have an index to speed up sorting for example.

There are probably SQL DBs that can run in memory.  You could even use a standard SQL DB and run it on a memory filesystem. There are also many NoSQL caching DBs which run strictly in memory (Redis, memcached,...).

If you tried to implement this by hand, I don't think Akka would be the way to go.  A plain collection would be more efficient.  I can't even imagine how your 5 millions actors would talk to one another to sort themselves out.  They would return their date and reference to themselves to the master and the master would do the sorting?  That would be more efficient directly with a collection.